# Where Clause with Alias Visual Basic & SQL

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

I have inherited a MS database, to work from, this database also links to other programs so I don't want to change the database tables itself.
I'm using Visual Basic 2010,
What I need to do is have a range of filters on this table and then one extra filter entered by the user.

e.g. they enter '50' and range '5' I need to search the dataset using the range of '45 to 55'
 This is my code so far for the dataset:

```
SELECT [CUTTER NO]
       ,CUTTER_ID
       ,[SIZE-Inches] 
       ,[MM-Across]
       ,[MM-Round]
       ,TYPE 
       ,[LEADING EDGE] 
       ,[CUTTER TYPE]
       ,ACROSS
       ,ROUND
       ,[WIDTH PAPERmm]
       ,[GAPS ACROSSmm]
       ,[GAPS ROUNDmm] 
       ,[Serial Number]
       ,[T G]
       ,Repeat
       ,[Repeat MM] 
       ,[L&G]
       ,Notes
FROM [Cutter List]
WHERE (TYPE <> 'DISCONTINUED') 
  AND (TYPE <> 'SPEC') 
  AND (CUTTER_ID <> NULL) 
  AND ([CUTTER TYPE] = 'MP') 
  AND (TYPE <> 'BUTT')
ORDER BY CUTTER_ID, [MM-Across]
```

What I need to type into this SQL is:

```
WHERE [MM-Across] LIKE @[MM-Across] and [MM-Round] LIKE @[MM-Round]
```

Which from what I can tell on the net is wrong as I cannot have [] in a where.

I even tried :

```
SELECT        [MM-Across] AS mmacross
FROM            [Cutter List]
WHERE        ('mmacross' LIKE '@mmacross')
```

This it accepts but I get an different error appear saying

> "The Schema returned by the new query differs from the base query."

What am I doing wrong? I don't understand the last error or how to avoid this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. You can definitely have brackets "[..]" in WHERE clauses, they just have to be in the correct places (just like anywhere else), and
2. You cannot use the brackets in ***variable*** or ***parameter*** references, and that means that, unlike columns, you cannot have special characters in their names, like "-" in "@MM-Across", so just change your parameter names to something like "@MM_Across".

Note that the **column** names are fine, it's your **parameter** and/or **variable** names that you have to change (I cannot tell which these are from your snippet).

So instead of this:

```
WHERE [MM-Across] LIKE @[MM-Across] and [MM-Round] LIKE @[MM-Round]
```

Try this:

```
WHERE [MM-Across] LIKE @MM_Across and [MM-Round] LIKE @MM_Round
```

Of course, you will also have to change the parameter/variable names wherever they are declared and passed in.  If you post the code that does this, I can show you how to change that also (thoguh it may be obvious by now).

Comment: Thank you, im still a little unsure how i can do this statement then, i can not alter the DB column names as they are linking to other programs. so im stuck with MM-Across.. what code would i need to put to change this to say MM_Across in the sql side because the  alias dont seem to be working, because i get the error "The Schema returned by the new query differs from the base query." at the moment im thinking of making a sql statment just to change headings to new alias. then do a 2nd sql statement from that. but im unsure if this is correct. thank you in advance

Comment: No, I did *not* say that you had to change the ***column*** names.  They can have special characters as long as you put the brackets around them.  It's your **parameter** and/or **variable** names that you have to change (I cannot tell which these are from you snippet).